# Running a symfony2 app using nginx and phpbb3 forum alongside each other

Tags: symfony, nginx, phpbb3

I have a symfony2 app running on www.sampledomain.com, with nginx as my webserver.

I'd like to run a phpbb3 forum in a subdirectory, www.sampledomain.com/forum

Symfony is capturing the request and posting a 404 as there is no route setup, however the phbb3 files exist in the /forum directory.

I've searched the documentation but cannot see a way to tell symfony2 to "pass through" requests to /forum. Is this possible?

Update #1: My nginx configuration, as requested:

```
server {
listen       80;
client_header_timeout 600s;
client_body_timeout 600s;

server_name www.sampledomain.com;
root   /home/ec2-user/www/sampledomain/www/web;
access_log /var/log/www.sampledomain.com.access_log;
error_log /var/log/www.sampledomain.com.error_log;

# strip app.php/ prefix if it is present
rewrite ^/app\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

location / {
    index app.php;
    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
}

location @rewriteapp {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
}

location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
#try_files       $uri /index.php;
fastcgi_index   index.php;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
include         fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    /home/ec2-user/www/sampledomain/www/web$fastcgi_script_name;
send_timeout 600s;
fastcgi_read_timeout 5m;
#fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

}

Comment: share your nginx configuration for the symfony site please then i can tell you where to put the condition to exclude forwarding requests to app.php for /forum

Comment: Added as requested @nifr - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the /forum location in nginx

```
location /forum {
    root [path to www]/forum;
    try_files $uri $uri/ [index location];
}
```

I haven't used phbb3 before, so I don't know the exact index location for it.